# Firebird and Delphi XE

Tags: delphi, firebird, delphi-xe, dbexpress

Can anyone explain what the default requirements are for Firebird on Delphi-XE and 64bit windows ?

From what I understand, you need fbclient.dll and the dbxfb.dll 
(with both being in app path or c:\windows\syswow64 ????)

Is there anything else needed ? (other than the service running if not using embedded) ?

Also does dbexpress work with fbembedded.dll ??

Any info on Firebird/DelphiXE/dbExpress appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Windows x64 you can:

1. install 32bit or x64 server software.
2. install 32bit fbclient.dll, because Delphi XE is a 32bit application.
3. install 32bit fbembed.dll, because Delphi XE is a 32bit application.

dbExpress should work with fbembed.dll. You need to set

```
VendorLib=fbembed.dll
```

Answer (score 0):

For the server side you will need:
DbxCommonDriver160.bpl
Dbxfb.dll
DBXFirebird
Driver160.bpl
fbclient.dll

Hope this helps.